# no puedo abrir puertos en CentOS 7

Tags: linux, puertos, centos7

tengo un problema, ya que no puedo abrir puertos en `CentOS 7`. Intento abrir el puerto 80 con la siguiente instrucción:

`--firewall-cmd --zone=trusted --add-port=80/tcp --permanent`

Con esto me confirma que el puerto esta abierto, reinicio el comando para aplicar `conf`.

`--firewall-cmd --reload`

Aplico un `nmap localhost 80` y este no me aparece en la lista, y por consecuencia no puedo levantar el servicio `http`

[image: configuración del puerto]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución para esto fue remover el paquete httpd y volverlo a instalar, un clásico.

remoción: `sudo yum remove httpd`
instalación: `sudo yum install httpd`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tu configuración de puertos es correcta con el comando `firewall-cmd`, y para que el comando `nmap` te muestre el puerto 80 como abierto, necesitas ejecutar una aplicación que escuche en ese puerto, ya que `nmap` solo muestra el status de puertos que están abiertos y en escucha.

Te lo muestro en un mi servidor CentOS 7, el servicio httpd (Apache) está apagado, como puedes ver en el status, después corro el comando `nmap localhost 80` y puedes ver que el puerto 80 no aparece en la lista de puertos abiertos:

[image: servicio httpd apagado]

Después  enciendo el servicio `httpd` con el comando `sudo systemctl start httpd`, mustro el status del servicio con `sudo systemctl status httpd` y ya se muestra encendido, finalmente corro otra vez `nmap localhost 80` y puedes ver que el comando ya muestra el puerto 80 como activo.

El uso de `nmap` muestra el estado de puertos abiertos y en escucha, ese es el motivo de porqué no te uestra el puerto 80 al no tener aplicación que escuche en el puerto.

Espero que te sirva la respuesta.

[image: Servicio httpd encendido]

Comment: +1, gracias, agradezco su respuesta, correcto lo que me menciona, solo que al tratar de activar el servicio de httpd me marca el siguiente error:
repito la sig. insutrucción:
**sudo systemctl start httpd** y el error es:
job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited whith error code. see Systemctlstatus httpd.service and journalctl -xe for details.